# SVG - inherit multiple colors/animations

Tags: svg

**What I try to do:**

Using a `<use>` element to copy an icon, and color the icon in two different colors when a specific class is added to the `<use>` element.

**The Icon:**

```
<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        id="red5" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 48.1 50.8">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{
      fill:#D73647;
      stroke:#000000;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
     }

    /* use.active .color-a{
      fill: green;
    }
    use.active .color-b{
      fill: blue;
    }*/ // Not working...
  </style>
  <g>
    <path class="st0 color-a" d="M2.3,20.2L11.8,20.2C11.8,20.2 12.5,10.9 22.3,11.2C22.3,11.2 28.5,11.1 32.3,16L26.3,22.4L47.5,22.4L47.5,2.7L40.4,9C40.4,9 36.1,0.4 23.6,0.5C23.6,0.5 4.8,-0.2 2.3,20.2z">
    </path>
    <path class="st0 color-b" d="M45.8,30.6L36.3,30.6C36.3,30.6 35.6,39.9 25.8,39.6C25.8,39.6 19.6,39.7 15.8,34.8L21.8,28.4L0.5,28.4L0.5,48.1L7.7,41.7C7.7,41.7 12,50.3 24.5,50.2C24.5,50.3 43.3,51 45.8,30.6z">
    </path>
  </g>
</symbol>
```

**The Use Element:**

```
<use id="svg_16" 
     xlink:href="#red5" transform="matrix(0.6730555893894703,0,0,0.7071457914654147,-239.09557391490307,-165.87702520953462) " 
     y="269.9999919533732" 
     x="473.99998587369964" 
     class="default-state" 
     fill="black"></use>
```

When the class of the `<use>` is changed from "default-state" to "active", I want the colors of the arrows to change (each to its own color).

**What I've tried so far:**

I understood that for the `paths` to change their color from the `<use>` element I have to change their CSS class to this:

```
.st0{
  fill: inherit; // <- changed
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

and the color classes to this:

```
use.active {
  fill: green;
}
```

but then when I set the class of `<use>` to "active" they both get the same color...

I would like to do the same thing for animations.

What am I missing? How do I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it: I would create one symbol and I would reuse twice the same path: once as it is and once rotated 180 degs. For the "default" state please remove the `active` class of the `g` element.

```css
.st0{
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
     }

     .active .color-a{
      fill: green;
    }
     .active .color-b{
      fill: blue;
    }

svg{width:90vh;border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 140 150" >
<symbol id="a" viewBox="0 0 48.1 50.8">
    <path class="st0 color-a" id="k" d="M2.3,20.2L11.8,20.2C11.8,20.2 12.5,10.9 22.3,11.2C22.3,11.2 28.5,11.1 32.3,16L26.3,22.4L47.5,22.4L47.5,2.7L40.4,9C40.4,9 36.1,0.4 23.6,0.5C23.6,0.5 4.8,-0.2 2.3,20.2z">
    </path>
  </symbol>

<g class="active" id="svg_16"  > 
  <use  class="color-a"
     xlink:href="#a"> 
</use>
  <use class="color-b" transform="rotate(180 70 75)"
     xlink:href="#a"> </use>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: in my case I'm coping all the SVG you created here and refer to it with `<use>`. and when that `<use>` is active I want the colors to apply.

Comment: let's say I have a building icon and I want to color each row of windows in different color when the building is active. how would you do it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. In my code there is a `<g>` element  with a class `.active` If you remove the class you get the default state.

Comment: This would be an other question and I need to see your code

Comment: I think I've answered this question. If you like my answer please accept it. If you need to ask something else please ask an other question. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: the new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537798/svg-inherit-multiple-colors. thank you for the help.