# How to use and style (selector) nested symbols in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have something like the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      grove > tree > triangle {
        /* some triangle styles */
      }

      #grove1 > tree > triangle {
        /* some triangle styles for grove 1 */
      }

      #grove2 > tree > triangle {
        /* some triangle styles for grove 2 */
      }

      #grove3 > tree > triangle {
        /* some triangle styles for grove 3 */
      }

      #grove3 > tree {
        /* animate the tree */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3000 3000">
      <defs>
        <symbol id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <polygon points="0,100 50,0 100,100" class="triangle" />
        </symbol>

        <symbol id="tree" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#triangle" width="100" height="100" />
        </symbol>
        
        <symbol id="grove" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="20" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="40" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="60" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="80" />
        </symbol>
      </defs>

      <use id="grove1" href="#grove" x="10" y="10" height="10"/>
      <use id="grove2" href="#grove" x="30" y="100" height="100"/>
      <use id="grove3" href="#grove" x="50" y="600" height="600"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that symbols are nested 3 levels deep. And the sizing definitions change at each symbol. For example, in the `grove` symbol, the `viewBox` is 100x100, but the trees which it contains also have their own view box of 100x100. The trees are sized to `10x10` in the grove, so they have a different scaling system.

Basically though, I compose these symbols into the `grove` symbol, then add those using `use` in 3 different places. Each one appears larger/closer than the one before. Or that's how it should work.

The question is how I can change the colors on these symbols efficiently and properly (best-practice). If I can do something like the example CSS above:

```
grove > tree > triangle {
  /* some triangle styles */
}
```

Or if I have to use JavaScript somehow to change the styles in this situation, or otherwise not really use symbols at all, or create symbol for every color variation I want (somehow).

Please let me know how I should structure this SVG system so I can properly style each chunk of stuff (each "grove" for example, and its contents).

Another example I'd like for this to handle is, say each tree has branches. I want to have 5 rows of trees, as if it's parallax and each row is further in the distance than the one before, and as such they get lighter and lighter. So I would like to set the color of the branches and the "leaves" (main tree triangle) to be lighter and lighter as they move back. In addition, maybe I want to slightly change the color of the trees at a specific row. So I should be able to do something like this:

```
#grove1 > tree > branch { /* style */ }
#grove1 > #tree1 { /* style */ }
#grove1 > #tree2 { /* style */ }
#grove1 > #tree2 > #branch1 { /* style */ }
#grove1 > #tree2 > #branch2 { /* style */ }
#grove1 > etc...
```

Basically how to style the nested symbols individually. If it's not possible, then what the design pattern is I should be using instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles can inherit into the children of a `<use>` see below:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #grove {
        /* some triangle styles */
      }

      #grove1 {
        /* some triangle styles for grove 1 */
        fill: red;
      }

      #grove2 {
        /* some triangle styles for grove 2 */
        fill: green;
      }

      #grove3 {
        /* some triangle styles for grove 3 */
        fill: gold;
      }

      #grove3 > tree {
        /* animate the tree */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3000 3000">
      <defs>
        <symbol id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <polygon points="0,100 50,0 100,100" class="triangle" />
        </symbol>

        <symbol id="tree" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#triangle" width="100" height="100" />
        </symbol>
        
        <symbol id="grove" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="20" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="40" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="60" />
          <use href="#tree" width="10" height="10" x="80" />
        </symbol>
      </defs>

      <use id="grove1" href="#grove" x="10" y="10" height="10"/>
      <use id="grove2" href="#grove" x="30" y="100" height="100"/>
      <use id="grove3" href="#grove" x="50" y="600" height="600"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

- You can style the `<symbol>` and it's children.
- You can style the `<use>` element.
- However you can't have selectors that cross the `<use>` "boundary".

  ```
  #myuse > #mysymbol-child
  ```

  will not work. You cannot use a selector to target a specific instance of that symbol.  Except by inheritance from the `<use>` as I have done in my example.

A symbol is a definition. If you give it a direct style, then that symbol with whatever style it has, will be used everywhere.  That includes things like animation.  If you animate the symbol, all instances of it will be animated the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the trick to do that is to set the properties you want to set differently for each instance of `<use>` to "inherit" or "currentColor" (or if they're inherited by default, don't set them, if you don't need to) and then place each `<use>` in a `<g>` and apply the style declarations to each `<g>`.

[SVG - inherit multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537798/svg-inherit-multiple-colors)